# Password enforcement for kid specific sites

Tags: security, passwords

If your site will be predominantly used by children of age group (5-15 yrs), would the password restrictions remain the same as it is enforced on a regular site.

(e.g. it should be at-least 6 characters in length and it should contain a mix of  alphanumeric and some special characters. Regular sites used by adults usually have restrictions like this).

What kind of restrictions would you put on kids or do you let the parents do the login for their respective children. From my experience even a 5 yr old, seems quite protective of his password but they do unknowingly share it with others.

Suggestions on any good practices would help and our site is primarily intended for practicing homework assessments.

Comment: So you want to build a site where we can send all the homework questions to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct would be not to create *yet another password / login combination*, but to use [OpenID](http://openid.net/add-openid/) instead

Answer (score 1):

I think you should think of it like this:

Password strength is not a question of  the age of a user its question of how easy it is to crack a password. So as such you shouldn't risk the security of your accounts on that level.

What I think is that in most case it is the browser that will handle the login most of the time (sessions, auto fill of the fields...).

you are concerned that a 5 year old would be protective, but he is not going to register, its the parents for the kid and once you add a keep me logged in option then the parent set it up and the kid can use it without worry.

hope that can help you